# React app works fine at local host but only serves index.html on IP

Tags: reactjs, networking, windows-11

I have built a simple React single page application.

For some reason the React javascript doesn't make the expected changes to the root element when the application is accessed at the machines IP.

I have tried, serving the application using:

```
$ npm start
```

or

```
$ npm build
$ npm install -g serve
$ serve -s build
```

The application works as expected at http://localhost:3000/ and http://127.0.0.1:3000/ but when I navigate to http:://IP0.IP1.IP2.IP3:3000/ I am only served index.html from the applications public directory. This behaviour is replicated if I try to navigate to the IP from a second machine...

Development Computer serving the app is Windows 11, web browsers tested Firefox, Chrome... Edge.

How can I configure the app to be served at an IP?